# Passing data between a parent window and a child popup window with jQuery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have the following HTML

```
<tr>
    <td class="label" valign="top">
        Affiliate Party
    </td>
    <td class="field">
        <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$MainContent$ExternalAccountAttributes$AffiliatePartyId" id="AffiliatePartyId" />
        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$ExternalAccountAttributes$AffiliatePartyName" type="text" id="AffiliatePartyName" class="PartyLookup" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

and the following Javascript/jQuery

```
$(".PartyLookup").after("<img src='Images/book_open.png' class='PartyLookupToggle' style='padding-left:4px;' />");

$(".PartyLookupToggle").click(function () {
    window.open("PartySearch.aspx", "PartySearch", "width=400,height=50");
    return false;
});
```

I need to be able to flag ANY PartyId input field with class="PartyLookup" so that it will modify the DOM and include the image next to the input field. The popup window returns data to populate both the hidden and text fields, but since the click() is generic I need to pass it the ID of the input field. I have no idea how to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: @micheel even in the popup you will have access to full dom ,,

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Script on parent page:

```
$(".PartyLookupToggle").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).prev().prev().attr("id");
    var name = $(this).prev().attr("id");

    var url = "PartySearch.aspx?id=" + id + "&name=" + name;

    window.open(url, "PartySearch", "width=400,height=50");
    return false;
});
```

Script on child page:

```
// Get the values from the URL using the jquery.query plug-in
var id = $.query.get("id");
var name = $.query.get("name");

// Get the values from the drop down
var newPartyId = $("#ddlMatchingParties").val();
var newPartyName = $("#ddlMatchingParties option:selected").text();

// Set them to the parent window
window.opener.$("#" + id).val(newPartyId);
window.opener.$("#" + name).val(newPartyName);

// Close the popup
window.close();
```

Comment: What does the .prev() do?

Comment: @Jon Gets the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements: http://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: This is one of the best posts on StackOverflow, one of the best! Lifesaver!

Answer (score 6):

It's very simple with jQuery, in your child window (popup) call your parent window objects there:

```
$("#txtCodCliente", opener.window.document).val("VALUE TO "); //assign

$("#btnSelCliente", opener.window.document).click();
```

with `opener.window.document` we tell to jQuery that the object is in window that opens the popup.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this instructional article: http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/window-child3.php

Essentially, you need to do this in the child window's form.  You'll be passing a value like so:

```
opener.document.f1.p_name.value="Any value";
```

Where `f1` is the ID of the form in the parent window and `p_name` is the name of the field in the form.

Once you have the value in a field on the parent, you can do whatever you like with it.

EDIT:

To pass info to the child window, the easiest method would probably be via query string, and then read the query string from the child window.  In this case, probably something like:

```
$(".PartyLookupToggle").click(function () {
    window.open("PartySearch.aspx?id=" + $(this).prev().attr('id'), "PartySearch", "width=400,height=50");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Yes, I do understand that. However, I need to pass the ID of the element is that the current $(this) is associated with to the child window so that when I return the values I know the "p_name" for the form elements.

Comment: Okay, but given the HTML structure I posted above in my question I need to find a way to jQuery to get the ID of the text field to the left of the click-able image (added to the DOM by jQuery).

Comment: Edited again.  Just use `.prev()` to traverse backwards to the text field, in order to get its ID.