# What to do after capturing the Access Credentials from OAuth

Tags: twitter, oauth, authorization, twitter-oauth

I am confused about what to do after I get the Access Credentials in successful OAuth authorization from Twitter.

What I did now is displaying a popup and got the Access Credentials back and have them as variable in my popup. What should I do now?

Should I pass the data back to my main window as described in the accepted answer here: [Passing data between a parent window and a child popup window with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350223/) or there's another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It guess it depends on your scenario. I would imagine that you either want to have "Sign in with Twitter" or "3-legged OAuth" functionality (most likely) as described on https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens.

You need to store the OAuth token somewhere so you are able to reuse it when you need to sign requests to the Twitter API going forward. And this could imply that you need to pass the data from your popup to your main window OR if you have some back-end code going on you could store it as part of the user session (or potentially the database). See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request.

To get the full picture on how to actually generate the signature from the various parameters see https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature, in essence you need to do a HMAC-SHA1 hash of a concatenated string of the parameters.