# Passing values from a pop up to a page and then closing pop up c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup

I have a pop up window doing some database queries(pop up popped up from the Default.aspx page).Now that I have the values I want to close the pop up and send these values to the Default.aspx page.

i tried Response.redirect(Default.aspx? + myvalues here) but it is opening the page in the pop up itself.

Any help please ?

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: on click event is like this         protected void click_(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?id= " + txtsmthng.text + "");
        }

Comment: you may need JavaScript to do this because in JavaScript you can have it open a new tab with what ever data, and as long it opened the tab it can close it I don't know if this will help

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Hidden value which store values hiddenly and again you can use it.

```
use it  <asp:HiddenField  runat="server"/> and store value in it from code behind
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening and closing a popup is a client side event. After you have got your values from Db, you can simply close the popup using window.close(); and then open the the Default.aspx using window.location.href="Default.aspx? + myvalues;

Comment: Could you please show the code how you are opening the pop up?

Comment: string appendThis = "var Mleft = (screen.width/2)-(760/2);var Mtop = (screen.height/2)-(700/2);window.open( 'ViewDetails.aspx?id="+txtAgent.Text+"', null, 'height=600,width=950,status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,location=no,top=\'+Mtop+\', left=\'+Mleft+\'' );";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", appendThis, true);

Comment: After getting the values in ViewDetails.aspx, you can store the values in hiddenfield and then using javascript close the popup window.close()and open default.aspx window.location.href= ' url...'  you can add the javascript code to that button which will close the popup

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you cant to that purely in c# because popup are created on client, you will have to use java script. After your work is finished with the popup window get reference to the window that ipened it by checking the property 'window.opener'. have a look here [Passing data between a parent window and a child popup window with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350223/passing-data-between-a-parent-window-and-a-child-popup-window-with-jquery) and still you have any doubt ask it again. hope this helps.