# Trying to pass a form value from pop-up window to Parent window in JS

Tags: javascript, html, popup, parent-child

Here is the Parent Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<img id="header" src="www.google.com" alt="image">

<input type="text" id="txtName" />

<input type="button" value="Select" onclick="imageReplacement();" />


<script>

function imageReplacement() {

var imager = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]
popitup();

}

var popup;
function popitup() {
    popup = window.open("Popup.html", "Popup", "width=300,height=100");
    popup.focus();
    return false
}

</script>
```

And here is the Pop-up code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<input name="imageNew" id="imageNew"></input>
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" value="Select" onclick="SetName();" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetName() {

        var txtName = window.opener.document.getElementById("txtName");
        txtName.value = document.getElementById("imageNew").value;
        window.close();

}
</script>
```

Right now whatever value is set on the pop-up window is not being transferred to to the parent window. Is this possible using javascript or do you need a web service to transfer the values?

Comment: This should get you started somewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350223/passing-data-between-a-parent-window-and-a-child-popup-window-with-jquery

Comment: BTW: you don't need "return false" unless the calling function is expecting a return value.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried whether it is possible to set a value of a html-element of a parent window within a child-window. But you can definitely set an attribute of the parent window-object. Furthermore define a onclose handler fot the popup-window that gets called when the popup is closed within the parent-window. When the close-handler is called you can extract the value of the attribute that you have set the the popup-window.

Hope this helps a little bit and gives you some idea to overcome this problem.