# Upload File PHP with popup

Tags: javascript, php, forms

Good day,
I was currently design a **form** that has 10 fields (3 of them requires upload file while the others are using normal `<input>` functions). Here i will only show a sample code for my form with the upload function that will trigger the popup box when the user clicks on the input on the form.

```
<form name="form1" action="process.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="form_ic" name="form_ic" size="30" onClick="return popup('pdf.php')">
    <a href="javascript:popup('pdf.php')">[Upload]</a>
</form>
```

For the upload file functions, i will need to do a popup box (pdf.php) from the original form php to show the terms stated for the files to be uploaded (eg. the file must be only .pdf and so on). The real upload function is only implemented on the form in pdf.php as follows:

```
<form name="pdf_upload" action="index.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploadfile" id="uploadfile">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" onClick="window.close();">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Here's the catch,

The purpose for this original form is to register the user profile. So what i want to do is that after user select the file from the upload popup box the file will be transferred back to the original form. The **name of the file** uploaded by the user will be displayed in the `<input type="text" id="form_ic">` back in the original form. The pdf file transferred back to the original form will be submitted along with other field details (eg. name, age, etc). For your information, since there are **3 fields** using the same upload function with popup, I will implement the same popup function.

I'm stuck of transferring the pdf file from the popup php to the original form php and to display the name of the uploaded file back in the original form php. I really need opinions from the community to solve this problem.

I am well aware that to display the name of .pdf file to the `<input>`, you'll require the javascript `.innerHTML` function, but i just can't retrieve the uploaded .pdf file from the pdf.php. It may be due to the problem with my code design. I'm not sure whether AJAX is required for my problem. Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350223/passing-data-between-a-parent-window-and-a-child-popup-window-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of your code is right, but you need to make change in your approach.

First, from your pop-up (pdf.php), you should upload the file. Currently you are calling **'window.close'**, hence the file is not submitted and upload functionality is not happening. While the modal box(Pop-Up) is open, let the file be uploaded and then through ajax, check if it is successful. If yes, then you can return the name of the file that it is saved as on server. This file name, you can pass to your main Form (Field should be Un-editable)

Second, you should change your JS code such that whenever you call the Pop-Up, you send the ID of the TextField of the Main Form, so that after file upload, the javascript sends the filename to the same field.

If you need more codebased example, then you should refer this example http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/upload-in-modal-window-and-pass-values-with-jquery/

Demo page of the above example can be found at: http://www.finalwebsites.com/demos/modal_upload_jquery_thickbox.php

Hope this helps to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you @Vinod Tigadi  for the feedback...so since I am using the modal php to upload the file to the database and save as a blob file, does that mean that i have to do two separate tables (one for profile table and another table for profile_image table?). My original table structure is only `profile` table which consists of the 11 fields, 10 mentioned in the question + primary key. So, since I am using the modal table to upload the file each time, that means I cannot use `insert into` query since it will create a new row of data and `update` query as well for the need of declaring new row.

Comment: If you are trying to save the Image data as a BLOB, then you may have to re-consider your design. Is there any particular reason that you want to save the BLOB in database? Usually the best way to save the files is, save the file and store the FilePath in the database. That's it. That will be a clean solution <br /> Regarding the Table Strucutre, for your file uploads, it will be good to have 2 tables, one as **PROFILE** and other as **FILES**. Let me know if you have any questions.